# Fancy header trouble when used with titletoc

Tags: pdftex, fancyhdr, titletoc

In a very big and complex document using the book class (so I can't reporduce easily a MWE, sorry), I want to use the fancyhdr package to display chapter name and number on the top left of even pages and section name and number on the top right of odd pages. For this I included the fancyhrd package and used the following:

```
\fancyhead[OR]{\bfseries \nouppercase{\rightmark}}
\fancyhead[EL]{\bfseries \nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\fancyfoot[EL,OR]{\thepage}
```

It works perfectly until I added the following command to my preamble:

```
\usepackage{titletoc}
\newcommand{\minitoc}{%
  \vfill
  \startcontents[chapters]
  \noindent
  \textbf{Chapter's outline}
  \titlerule[1pt]
  \printcontents[chapters]{}{1}{}
  \medskip
  \titlerule[1pt]
  \newpage
}
```

and then use it at the beginning of each chapter

```
\chapter{Context}
\label{ctx}
\minitoc{}
.....
```

It seems that the line breaking fancyhdr is `\printcontents[chapters]{}{1}{}` SO my question is what am I missing here, any known incompmatibilities between `titletoc` and `fancyhdr`, am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: Can you make a compilable minimal example?

Comment: @egreg unfortunately not easily. I think I'll wait a little to see if someone already encountered such an error before trying to make a MWE (I guess that it'll take some time but also gives me the source of the problem)

Comment: I think it is a problem of your command minitoc did you try without fancyhdr?

Comment: Use `titlesec`'s header/footer package rather than `fancyhdr`. It is likely to get along better with `titletoc`. If you still have trouble, an MWE. (And, yes, you *can* produce one. You just mean you don't want to go to the trouble!)

Comment: @ManuelSelva I just add \mbox{} befor the last \titlerule[1pt] and every thing is good. just a question why do you use \vfill

Comment: @ManuelSelva may be you want to edit the title of your question. It is not incompmatibilities problem.

Comment: @cfr I dind't said I can't but I can't easily ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Load  `titlesec` with option `pagestyles`, remove `fancyhdr` and add this code to your preamble:

```
 \newpagestyle{myfancy}{%
 \sethead[\bfseries\thechapter~\chaptertitle][][]{}{}{\bfseries\thesection~\sectiontitle}
 \setfoot{}{\thepage}{}
 }
\pagestyle{myfancy}
```